# Can you give me a simple example when I am to use "monitor" because it cannot be done with "lock"?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking

MSDN tells me that using lock is equivalent to using monitor [but is more concise and less error prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020064/why-does-the-lock-insure-that-the-underlying-monitor-is-released-and-direct-usag).

Can you give me a simple  (single process) example why would I be forced to use `Monitor` because it cannot be done with `lock`?

Comment: Based on your quote what makes you think you would ever be forced to use `Monitor` directly instead of `lock`?

Comment: Because I see numerous code examples with its use. Also, why, then, is it made available?

Comment: @Fulproof: Because C# does not have macros ;p Same for other syntax sugar in C# like `using`, `foreach`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can you give me a simple (single process) example why would I be forced to use monitor when the lock is not enough?

Sure. Suppose you want to take an action *if you can* acquire the lock, but if some other object already owns it, you don't want to block for longer than a certain time:

```
bool gotMonitor = false;

try
{
    Monitor.TryEnter(monitor, 500, ref gotMonitor);
    if (gotMonitor)
    {
        // Okay, we're in the lock. We can do something useful now.
    }
    else
    {
        // Timed out - do something else
    }
}
finally
{
    if (gotMonitor)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(monitor);
    }
}
```

(Note that I'm deliberately *not* [using the overload of `TryEnter` which just returns success/failure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h9d380.aspx) - the version I'm using is more reliable, as the setting of the `ref` parameter is atomic with respect to the lock acquisition.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Not absolutely related to the question itself, but there're also a lot of scenarios where ReaderWriterLockSlim will work better than `Monitor` as it easily supports recursion.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Indeed - I was only trying to give an example where it's worth using `Monitor` directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah! Don't misunderstand me, it's just a suggestion so maybe the OP may discover other options :)